# Waiting for a specified duration in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, wait

Is there a more straightforward way to wait for a specific amount of time in Cocoa than what I have come up with below?

```
- (void) buttonPressed {
    [self makeSomeChanges];

    // give the user some visual feedback and wait a bit so he can see it
    [self displayThoseChangesToTheUser];
    [self performSelector:@selector(buttonPressedPart2:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.35];
}

- (void) buttonPressedPart2: (id)unused {
    [self automaticallyReturnToPreviousView];
}
```

Just to be clear, there is no **functional** problem with this code -- my only beef is a **stylistic** one.  In my case the flow is simple enough that it works, but try to encapsulate it or throw in some conditionals and things could turn ugly.  It's been kind of nagging at me that I couldn't find a way to wait and then return to that same point in code like this (fictitious) example:

```
- (void) buttonPressed {
    [self doStuff];
    [UIMagicUnicorn waitForDuration:0.35];
    [self doStuffAfterWaiting];
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449035/12484

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There is

```
usleep(1000000);
```

and

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
```

both of which will sleep for 1 second.

Comment: and both of which will block the thread from doing anything else. bad, if it's in the main U.I. thread.

Comment: True.  If you need the UI to be responsive during this period, the approach suggested in the question, an NSTimer firing once (like you suggest), or a background thread performing this delay would be better.

Comment: Thanks -- that's what I was wondering about, probably would have stumbled onto it had 'sleep' been one of the several synonyms for 'wait' I had thought to search on.  Thanks also Pestilence for the caveats about when *not* to use these.

Comment: The approach that uses RunAfterDelay with a block won't block your main thread.

Answer (score 13):

Here's the NSTimer way of doing it. It's might be even uglier than the method you're using, but it allows repeating events, so I prefer it.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f 
                                 target:self
                               selector: @selector(doSomething:) 
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
```

You want to avoid something like usleep() which will just hang your app and make it feel unresponsive.

Comment: "`You want to avoid something like usleep() which will just hang your app and make it feel unresponsive.`" Pretty sure this is only true if you called `usleep` from the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it exists (yet), but with blocks in 10.6 (or [PLBlocks](http://code.google.com/p/plblocks/) in 10.5 and on the iPhone) it should be pretty easy to write a little wrapper like `performBlock:afterDelay:` that does exactly what you want without the need to sleep the entire thread. Would be a useful little piece of code indeed.

Mike Ash has [written about an approach like this on his blog](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html):

```
NSString *something = ...;
RunAfterDelay(0, ^{
    NSLog(@"%@", something);
    [self doWorkWithSomething: something];
});
```

Comment: Or just use NSTimer's scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:

Comment: might not have been there in 10.6… cannot remember

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use an [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer?language=occ) and have it send a "doStuffAfterWaiting" message as your callback. Any kind of "sleep" will block the thread until it wakes up. If it's in your U.I. thread, it'll cause your app to appear "dead." Even if that's not the case, it's bad form. The callback approach will free up the CPU to do other tasks until your specified time interval is reached.

This [doc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html) has usage examples and discusses the differences on how & where to create your timer.

Of course, performSelector:afterDelay: does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with a simple `usleep`? I mean, except for the sake of "Cocoa purity", it's still much shorter than other solutions :)

Comment: It blocks the thread. If it's called in the main, you're effectively killing the run loop and the app will appear "dead"

Comment: Then don't call from the main

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind an asynchronous solution, here you go:

```
[[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self doStuffAfterWaiting];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

To wait, there is [`NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsthread/1413673-sleepfortimeinterval?language=objc).

This solution was actually taken from: [What's the equivalent of Java's Thread.sleep() in Objective-C/Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829449/thread-sleep-in-objective-c)