# How to add delay in execution of successive iterations in for loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, for-loop

In my iphone, I want to ensure that in the for loop there is some amount of delay between the successive iterations.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread.sleep in objective -c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829449/thread-sleep-in-objective-c)

Comment: Just out of curiosity; why would you want to do that?

Comment: Sorry I think ChrisF is correct.

Answer (score 0):

forloopstart{

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateTextLabelWithString:) withObject:@"sleep 5 worked" afterDelay:5.0];
```

}

-(void)updateTextLabelWithString:(NSString*)theString
{

```
NSLog(@"theString is : %@ \n\n",theString);
```

}